# Understanding algorithms for numeric constraint solving

Tags: rules-and-constraints

As an educational exercise, I am looking to implement a constraint solver from scratch. However, since the field is entirely new to me, I am at a loss of where to begin with background research.

The problems I aim to address are mostly sets of inequalities, such as `a < b && b < c`, where `a`, `b`, `c` are integers. (While it is possibly not relevant to the question at this stage, I do aim to address problems with other numeric types later on).

The algorithms I have looked at so far are in the *branch-and-bound* and *branch-and-cut* categories mostly. However, if I am looking for a generic, efficient algorithm, is this what I want to be looking at? It would be very helpful to receive some guidelines here.

Comment: Proof assistants are a good place to start researching to understand the space you're referring to. COQ and HOL are two that are widely known. Dependently typed languages like AGDA can suffice as proof assistants as well but that isn't strictly their purpose.